# How to pass socket callback to other modular events

Tags: node.js

I have a question to which I am trying to figure out the answer

For example, I structured the sockets like this

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
});
```

```
// sockets events
const onConnection = require('./sockets/events/connection');
```

```
io.on("connection", onConnection);
```

```
const search = require('./s');earch

const onConnection = async (socket) => {
    console.log(`Client connected ${socket.id}`);

    socket.on('search', search);

    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        console.log(`Client disconnected with reason: ${reason}`)
    })
};

module.exports = onConnection;
```

But in that search function, I would also like to pass the "socket" argument so that I can still have access to the socket functions

```
const onSearch = async (socket) => {
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(500);
}
  
module.exports = onSearch;
```

So my question is when I access that event (search) in socket.on, how could I send the socket further?

I tried to pass as a function

```
socket.on('search', metasearch(socket);
```

But it didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `socket.io` but you should be able to refactor the callback like this:

```js
const onSearch = (socket) => async (data) => {
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(500);
}
  
module.exports = onSearch;
```

and then

```js
socket.on('search', search(socket));
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above approach, if you want to avoid creating wrapper functions one thing you can do is simply create non arrow functions and make use of `this`.

```
// onConnection method which attaches listeners
//socket is available here

const onConnection = async (socket) => {
...
socket.on('search', metasearch);
...
}
```

```
function metasearch (args) {
console.log(this.id);
};
```